# Find multiple radius in one contour using OpenCV Python

Tags: python, opencv, least-squares

I would like to approximate a contour with different circle segments with radii. If I have a circle segment with only one radius, it is no problem to approximate this radius with the circle fit function cf.least_squares_circle().

But if the contour has different circle segments with different radii, then the radius is completely averaged.

[Image 1 single radius](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAXKC.png)

[image2 multiple radius](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1WG7.png)

is there another way than using cf.least_squares_circle()? Thank you for your help.

Here is my code so far:

[result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RR4xs.png)

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import circle_fit as cf

# load image as color to draw
img = cv2.imread(r'image.png')

##img Height:
print((img.shape[0]))
##Bildbreite:
print((img.shape[2]))

PY = []
PX = []

for j in range (img.shape[2]):
    for i in range (img.shape[0]):
        if img[i,j,0] != 0:
            PY.append(i)
            PX.append(j)

PXY = np.zeros((len(PX), 2))
for n in range(len(PX)):
    PXY[(n, 1)] = PX[n]
    PXY[(n, 0)] = PY[n]

xc, yc, r, _ = cf.least_squares_circle(PXY)
cv2.circle(img, (int(yc), int(xc)), int(r), (0, 0, 255), thickness=1, lineType=8, shift=0)
cv2.imshow("output", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hey Friedrich, thank you. I updated the above code.